# Error Installing virtualbox-dkms: kernel package linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic is not supported

Tags: apt, kernel, virtualbox, dkms

I am currently trying to get VirthalBox back up and running on Ubuntu 20.04 but during the installation of the `virtualbox-dkms` package, I got following error:

```
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic is not suppo
rted
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-34-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
```

How can I resolve this issue so I can have VirtualBox working again?

Comment: Why do you have a 4.15 kernel on 20.04? 20.04 comes with a 5.4 kernel, so you're several releases behind the expected kernel version.

Comment: @muru That is the version that is currently installed. And checking for updates I get no suggestion to update them.

Comment: Well, how did you end up in that situation then?

Comment: @muru I upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04 and on installing VirtualBox, I got the error.

Comment: Even 19.10 had kernel 5.3. Are you using a VPS or something?

Comment: @muru No I am not using VPS but it's probably because I am on a school network where I use a copy of the repo that the school provides because I am unable to use the original repos due the school network being behind a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up resolving the problem by manually installing a newer version of the kernel. I found a tutorial on [It's Foss](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/) which guided me on downloading and installing the kernel.

What I did was to manually download the deb packages for the kernel (Version 5.6.4) from the [Ubuntu Kernel Site](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D) which includes the following files (Mine is the 64 bit architecture):

- linux-headers-`VERSION-NUMBER`_all.deb
- linux-headers-`VERSION-NUMBER`_amd64.deb
- linux-image-`VERSION-NUMBER`_amd64.deb
- linux-modules-`VERSION-NUMBER`_amd64.deb

I placed all those files in a seperate folder, I opened a terminal window and changed to the path of that folder using the command: `cd {folder_path}` where `{folder_path}` is the full path to the folder where I downloaded the deb files for the kernel.

Then I installed them by running the command: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

After that, all I had to do was restart my computer and I was updated to the newer kernel version.